# Error loading xnb file in Monogame from fbx

Tags: c#, xna, porting, monogame, fbx

I'm trying to import a fbx file from XNA to Monogame Android (with Visual Studio) using the Monogame content project to process fbx files into xnb.
The project compiles correctly but when I import the xnb file into Android project and run it, the game doesn't work:

ContentLoadException:
Could not load Models/maze1 asset as a non-content file!

In Android project I've already set the build action to “Content” and the CopyTo setting at “Copy if Newer” or “Copy Always”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the Content option in Monogame and check you've selected "Android", then compile. If the xnb file doesn't work I think there's something wrong in your model.